# removing elements of arrqy error

Tags: arrays, qt

I have a csv file which contains the numbers of buttons. I want to make a function that reads these numbers and set the number of a class that I have made and called FButton.

First I have declared an array of FButtons in my header file.

```
FButton buttons[10];
```

Now in the cpp file I have written the following code to set the numbers of the buttons:

```
QFile f("Buttons.csv");

if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    int i=0;

    QString data;
    data = f.readAll();
    QStringList vals = data.split(';');

    while (!vals.isEmpty())
    {
        buttons[i].setNumber(vals[0].toInt());
        vals.removeAt(0);
        i++;
    }

    f.close();
 }
```

The function setNumber is given by:

```
void FButton::setNumber(int butNumber)
{
    number=butNumber;
}
```

It is possible for me to build the code, but when i try to run it an error occurs:

GUI.exe is no longer working.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you traced your program with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you have more values in your CSV than the size of `buttons` array (or whatever collection it is) ? Or having uninitialized objects in `buttons` ?